# Winston JS, format daily rotate filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I'm trying to use Winston JS to log in console and in different files.
At the moment the console log works fine but can't give to the file the name that I want: `2017-05-31_Node.log`, what I get is `2017-05-31_Node.log2017-05-31`.

Here is my transport code:

```
    import { DailyRotateFileTransportInstance, transports } from 'winston';
    import * as dailyRotateFile from 'winston-daily-rotate-file';
    import * as path from 'path';
    import * as moment from 'moment';

    import { LogConstants } from '../../constants';

    transports.DailyRotateFile = dailyRotateFile;

    export let DailyRotateFileTransport = new transports.DailyRotateFile({
        level: 'Error',
        filename: path.join(LogConstants.LogsDirectory, `${ moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') }_Node.log`),
        datePattern: ''
    });
```

How can I have a file without the date at the end?

Answer (score 0):

can you try：

```js
{
level: 'Error',
filename: LogConstants.LogsDirectory,
datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd_Node.log'
}
```